# Extract data from JSON in vanilla Java/Camel/Spring

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, jolokia

I am trying to write a Camel route to get JMX data from an ActiveMQ server through the Jolokia REST API. I was able to successfully get the JSON object from the ActiveMQ server, but I am running into an issue where I cannot figure out how to parse the JSON object in my Camel route. Camel is integrated with Jackson, Gson, and XStream, but each of those appear to require an extra library that I do not have. Camel also has support for JSONPath, but it requires another library that I do not have. All of my research so far seems to point to using a new software library, so I am looking for someone who knows a solution to possibly save me some time from trying several more dead ends.

The big catch is that I am trying to parse JSON with something that comes with Java/Camel/Spring/ActiveMQ/apache-commons. I would prefer a solution that only uses Camel/Spring XML, but another solution using Java would work (maybe JXPath with Apache Commons?).

The reason I am trying to use libraries that I currently have is the long process that our company has for getting new software libraries approved. I can wait several months to get a library approved or I can write my own specialized parser, but I am hoping there is some other way for me to extract some of the information from the JSON object that I am getting from the Jolokia JMX REST API in ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JSOn library out of the box in Java itself. But there is a RFE to maybe add that in a future Java release, maybe Java 9.

So if you want to parse json, you need to use a 3rd party library. So you better get your company to approve a library.

camel-core 2.15.x has a json scheme parser we use to parse the component docs json schemas that is shipped now. But its not a general purpose json parser, but can parse simple schemas.

Its at `org.apache.camel.util.JsonSchemaHelper`